# GameCenter not working, authentication and leaderboard not showing

Tags: swift2, game-center

With Swift 2, GameCenter is not working for me. The authentication ViewController is not showing up... Here is my func `authenticateLocalPlayer()`:

```
func authenticateLocalPlayer() {
    var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer()
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController: UIViewController?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (viewController != nil) {
            self.presentViewController(viewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("Not Authenticated. ")
        } else {
            print("Authenticated. ")
        }
    }
}
```

It is returning "Not Authenticated" every time, but is not presenting the ViewController. Any solution?

Comment: It might help if you specify whether this happens in the Device, Simulator, or both. Also, does it happen only when running on iOS 9 Devices/Simulators, or does it happen also when running on iOS 8?

Comment: What is `self` in your code?

Comment: UIViewController @Adam

Comment: It happens in both device and simulator and also both iOS 9 and iOS 8. Sorry for not clarifying @NicolasMiari

Comment: Then, the problem must reside in the iOS 9 SDK, not in OS 9 itself (otherwise, it wouldn't affect iOS 8).

Comment: Try replacing self with your root view controller.

Comment: @parth not sure why you're not getting the login controller, but there's another issue with your `authenticatHandler`. If an error occurs, you will receive a non-nil `NSError` with a nil `viewController`. Since your code doesn't check the `NSError`, it will assume a nil VC means the player is authenticated, which would be erroneous.

Comment: @Thunk Thanks for that, I believe that was the problem, I will check it out! Thanks!

Comment: make sure you invoke this method from the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

This solution presents the viewController correctly using Swift 2 in Xcode 7.0.

Note that I have changed the code before the if statement begins. I believe the syntax may have changed in a recent software update as I had this problem too.

In my app I called authenticateLocalPlayer() in the viewDidLoad() method of the GameViewController class.

```
func authenticateLocalPlayer() {

    let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController, error) -> Void in

        if (viewController != nil) {
            self.presentViewController(viewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else {
            print((GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated))
        }
    }
}
```